# Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1) in Fortran

Tags: vector, fortran, fortran90

i'm not very good at programming but unfortunately it'a compulsory i learn it, moving on i have been asked to do an assignment on programming for vectors.

i have to work out the dot product and the dot product

i got this far:

```
REAL :: x , y , z
END TYPE myvector

CONTAINS



TYPE ( myvector ) FUNCTION vect_add (a , b )
 IMPLICIT NONE
 TYPE ( myvector ) , INTENT (IN) :: a , b
 vect_add % x = a % x + b % x
 vect_add % y = a % y + b % y
 vect_add % z = a % z + b % z
 END FUNCTION vect_add


TYPE ( myvector ) FUNCTION vect_scale ( vector , scalar )
 IMPLICIT NONE
 TYPE ( myvector ) , INTENT (IN) :: vector
 REAL , INTENT (IN) :: scalar

 vect_scale % x = vector % x * scalar
 vect_scale % y = vector % y * scalar
 vect_scale % z = vector % z * scalar
 END FUNCTION vect_scale

TYPE ( myvector ) FUNCTION vect_sub (a , b )
 IMPLICIT NONE
 TYPE ( myvector ) , INTENT (IN) :: a , b
 vect_sub % x = a % x - b % x
 vect_sub % y = a % y - b % y
 vect_sub % z = a % z - b % z
 END FUNCTION vect_sub

REAL FUNCTION vect_dot (a , b )
 IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: a, b

 vect_dot % x = a % x * b % x
 vect_dot % y = a % y * b % y
 vect_dot % z = a % z * b % z
 END FUNCTION vect_dot

TYPE ( myvector ) FUNCTION vect_cross (a , b )
 IMPLICIT NONE
 TYPE ( myvector ) , INTENT (IN) :: a , b
 vect_cross % x = (a % x * b % y) - (b % x * a % y)
 vect_cross % y = (a % y * b % z) - (b % y * a % z)
 vect_cross % z = (a % z + b % x) - (a % x * b % z)
 END FUNCTION vect_cross



end program assign_9_2
```

when i compile it, i get an error message saying: Error:

assign_9_2.f90:42.1:

vect_dot % x = (a % x * b % x)
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
assign_9_2.f90:43.1:

vect_dot % y = (a % y * b % y)
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
assign_9_2.f90:44.1:

vect_dot % z = (a % z * b % z)
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

can someone please help me know where i've gone wrong thank you.

Comment: sorry ill remove it i just need help

Comment: Which line did the compiler report? Include full error message!

Comment: im sorry,

 assign_9_2.f90:42.1:

 vect_dot % x = (a % x * b % x)
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
assign_9_2.f90:43.1:

 vect_dot % y = (a % y * b % y)
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
assign_9_2.f90:44.1:

 vect_dot % z = (a % z * b % z)
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `vect_dot` is `REAL` and not `TYPE(my_vect)` and the arguments `a` and `b` are too.

Comment: after removing all the spaces

Comment: Sorry, I was completely wrong. The spaces can remain. The real error is now in the answer.

Comment: thats what the assignment tells me to do to quote it says the 2 functions should be declared as 'REAL FUNCTION vect_dot(a, b)
and
TYPE(myvector) FUNCTION vect_cross(a, b)'

Comment: then change the inside but don't try to access components of a real number, it ain't got any.

Comment: sorry, but i dont understand

Comment: what should it look like?

Comment: You just can't do `a % x` when `a ` is just `real `. I cant write the homework for you.